# how to start this process

Tags: c#

I want to know how can I start this process wiht C# :

```
TestFile.exe -i "c:\Program Files\My App\MyContextMenuExtension.dll" "c:\Program Files\My App\LogicNP.EZShellExtensions.dll"
```

How can I send that two argumant toprocess ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string arguments = 
    "-i \"c:\\Program Files\\My App\\MyContextMenuExtension.dll\"";

arguments += " \"c:\\Program Files\\MyApp\\LogicNP.EZShellExtensions.dll\"";

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("TestFile.exe", arguments);
```

Comment: @pedram - It got left out while I was trying to make things more readable. It's there now.

Answer (score 1):

```
Process.Start("TestFile.exe", @"-i \"c:\Program Files\My App\MyContextMenuExtension.dll\" \"c:\Program Files\My App\LogicNP.EZShellExtensions.dll\"");
```

Dont forget the path in first parameter.
Second parameter is your arguments, each separated by a space (if there is space in your arguments, you need to put them inbetween \"

Comment: Also forgot to escape the slashes.

Comment: You forgot to use escape characters or the @ prefix for the arguments string... I prefer the @ prefix. :)