# Execute a Batch File Which in Turn Starts a Process on a Remote Machine

Tags: c#, batch-file, dos

Here I have 2 requirements:

1. Need a batch file to start a process on remote machine.
2. C# program to run batch file. I came across using process info class but I am confused over  calling WaitForExit. Why should we call that method? If we don't call that method what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a process (just change this to point to your bat file):

[how to start this process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424601/how-to-start-this-process)

And write a .bat file that does one of the things suggested here:

[Run application or Process on a remote computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677867/run-application-or-process-on-a-remote-computer)

Comment: Thanks for youre immediate reply Quackenbush. But in second link sloution is in VB Script. Can I get the same code in C# or some dos commands to start a process in remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

From your requirements, don't call WaitForExit. Its necessary only if you are waiting the launched process to complete before continue with your code. If you don't call, your program continues as soon as you have called Process.Start

Comment: Thanks for reply Steve. Will try it.